# How to create listview with links to assets html file?

Tags: android, html, listview

I have an activity which I want to show ListView with list of topics, which linked to html files in assets folder.

Here is a code for files from *res/raw* folder (they named as n0.txt, n1.txt etc.):

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.view);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //getting string and forming resource name

        Context context = getBaseContext(); //getting context

        //reading text file from resources by name
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.falcon5f.carguide;"));

        WebView wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
        wWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); //uploading text to webview
    }

    public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) //reading text raw txt file
    {
         InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
             String line;
             StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

             try {
               while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                   text.append(line);
                   text.append('\n');
                 }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               return null;
           }
             return text.toString();
    }
}
```

How can I do this for html files from assets (they named n0.html etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `InputStream` to a file from your assets you could use :

```
InputStream is=getAssets().open("n0.txt");
```

then you should process the stream as you did with your raw resources.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm a begginer in android programming. Could you write a listing with changes which I should do?

Comment: Sorry, usually on SO we are here to give you some help/hints/directions not to give you the entire code. I do not have time for that.

Comment: Only two questions. How can I change this: Context context = getBaseContext(); //getting context //reading text file from resources by name String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.falcon5f.carguide;")); And this: public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) //reading text raw txt file { InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId); Please, help

Comment: Activity extends Context. When you refer to Context from an Activity, you can make use of `this`.